# Can you make same page anchor jump to a scroll position rather than an actual anchor?

Tags: html, anchor

On this [Dev page](http://workwave.joomlatest01.mms-dev.com/)

the blue down "auto scroll" arrow under the headline text uses a simple anchor to jump to a spot on the page (and some javascript to slow down the scroll, but I don't think that matters as far as my question goes).

As you can see, I'm also using Skrollr to animate objects and when you scroll down manually, the page kind of 'sticks' when the iMac reaches the top of the page.  THAT is where I'd like the "auto scroll" arrow button to jump to and STOP.

Right now, it scrolls to that spot, but then keeps going a little further.

I've tried putting the anchor element in all different spots, but none get the desired resting place. That got me wondering if you can specify that an anchor scrolls down to a certain scroll position (for example, 300 pixels) rather than to an actual anchor element.

In other words, my skrollr code fixes the monitor to the top of the page when the user scrolls 300 pixels.  So that is where I need the "auto scroll" down arrow to jump to.

Anyone know if this is possible, or have another idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks both of you. Tim's 3rd option was exactly what I was looking for. If I had posted the code Jack wanted, I'm sure he would have said the same thing (sorry about that). Thanks again!....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about modifying the `.scrollTop()` method which you are already using to scroll to the top of the monitor `div` rather than the anchor?

```
$("a#anchor1").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("div#monitor").offset().top
    }, 2500);
    return false;
});
```

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timothyjmullen/doofq7Le/1/).

If you need it to scroll a few pixels past that div to make it work correctly then you can always add or subtract from that point.

```
$("a#anchor1").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($("div#monitor").offset().top) + 100
    }, 2500);
    return false;
});
```

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timothyjmullen/doofq7Le/2/).

If you want to scroll a certain number of pixels down without referring to any of those elements, just set the scroll on the body element.

```
$("a#anchor1").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($("body").offset().top) + 300
    }, 2500);
    return false;
});
```

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timothyjmullen/doofq7Le/3/).

You can read more about the `.scrollTop()` method in [jQuery's API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), or if you would rather use pure JS you can read about the [HTML DOM scrollTop property here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a little javascript - probably leveraging what you've already got in there to slow the scroll. Can you post that code?

Basically, through one method or another, your scroll code involves telling the page to scroll to its destination smoothly. All you'll have to do is provide a different destination than what it's naturally expecting.